# Why isn't my math.random function working?

Tags: javascript

Here's the code I'm running:

```
var random = math.random();

function randomTest() {
if (random<0.33) {
    document.write("first")
}
else if (random<0.40) {
    document.write("second")
}
else if (random<0.80) {
    document.write("third")
}
else {
    document.write("last")
}
}
document.write(randomTest());
```

Just trying to test out some things with math.random and functions, as I'm a beginner, and wondering why nothing is being written to the document when I run this. Any help is appreciated, much thanks.

Comment: It's `Math`, not `math`. JavaScript is case-sensitive. Some basic debugging would have given you the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its `Math` with an uppercase M. Also, you do not need to do `document.write(randomTest())` as `randomTest()` does not return anything.

```js
var random = Math.random();

function randomTest() {
  if (random < 0.33) {
    document.write("first");
  } 
  else if (random < 0.40) {
    document.write("second");
  } 
  else if (random < 0.80) {
    document.write("third");
  } 
  else {
    document.write("last");
  }
}
randomTest();
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the answer is due to a typo and try and farm the rep from it. These types of questions are low quality and you should instead vote to close them as off-topic due to a typo.